# Get all evaluation metrics after classification in pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, multiclass-classification

I have trained a model and want to calculate several important metrics such as `accuracy`, `precision`, `recall`, and `f1 score`.

The process I followed is:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='features',labelCol='label')
lrModel = lr.fit(train)
lrPredictions = lrModel.transform(test)

from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator

eval_accuracy = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
eval_precision = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="precision")
eval_recall = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="recall")
eval_f1 = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="f1Measure")

eval_auc = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="label", rawPredictionCol="prediction")

accuracy = eval_accuracy.evaluate(lrPredictions)
precision = eval_precision.evaluate(lrPredictions)
recall = eval_recall.evaluate(lrPredictions)
f1score = eval_f1.evaluate(lrPredictions)

auc = eval_accuracy.evaluate(lrPredictions)
```

However, it can only calculate `accuracy` and `auc`, but not the three others. What should I modify here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.metricName), for the F1 measure, precision, and recall, the relevant arguments of `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` should be respectively

```
metricName="f1"
metricName="precisionByLabel"
metricName="recallByLabel"
```